# Rails - how to Create a Mail object ,Mail.new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

using rails 3, I want to learn how to create a ActionMailer Mail object and can't much docs online. I have the following work:

```
message_all = Mail.new(:from => 'frooooom', :to => 'tooooo', :cc => 'cccccccc', :subject => 'SUBJECTasddsadsadasdsa')
```

Question is now, how do I add a HTML and TEXT Body to that? Bonus points for also showing an example of how to add attachements.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the  [mail gem's documentation](https://github.com/mikel/mail)?  This example is mostly pulled from there:

```
message_all = Mail.new do
  to 'nicolas@test.lindsaar.net.au'
  from 'Mikel Lindsaar <mikel@test.lindsaar.net.au>'
  subject 'First multipart email sent with Mail'
  text_part do
    body 'This is plain text'
  end
  html_part do
    content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    body '<h1>This is HTML</h1>'
  end
end
```

I believe you can still pass the headers in a hash as you were doing before, but the text_part/html_part business should go in the block.

Info on attachments is in that link I provided above.

Comment: that's great, I hadn't  seen this... Then once I have the message_all object, how can O output the message_all text_part?

Comment: @AnApprentice, if I understand you correctly (you want to output the text form of the e-mail?), you just call `.to_s` on the message object.

Answer (score 0):

Google '"rails 3" email templates" yields this:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-multipart-emails

Check out section 2.7 on sending multi-part emails.

Comment: cool but the thing is I don't want to send emails. That's easier. I want to build a Mail object, so I can store it in the database and use it later. Thoughts?